# datastore-indexes.xml doesn't work, creates no index after deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have created a Kind called User in Google App Engine datastore, and I am trying to add an index for this kind.

Firstly, I followed https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/indexconfig to create index by adding datastore-indexes.xml inside war/WEB-INF, but it doesn't work, no index is created after I deploy to app engine.

code in my datastore-indexes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="false">
    <datastore-index kind="User" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="area" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="coins_balance" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

Then I followed https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/indexref, I created an index.yaml and run `gcloud app deploy index.yaml`, this time index is actually created.

So can anyone help me understand why datastore-indexes.xml in my case doesn't work, thanks.

Comment: How did you deployed to App Engine? Like `appcfg.sh update_indexes path/to/datastore-indexes.xml`? Because if you don't explicitly/manually deploy this file, as you later did, it won't have any effect.

Comment: I see, but I don't have appcfg.sh, only got gcloud, so I guess I'll stick with index.yaml

Comment: Yeah, if you use gcloud instead of appcfg, stick with the yaml format described [in here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/indexref-yaml), but the logic to follow is the same, you have to run `gcloud app deploy index.yaml` for the indexes to deploy.

Comment: thank you very much Mangu, issue solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in the [java index config](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/indexconfig) page and noted in the comments, datastore-indexes.xml is only supported through appcfg.sh at this time.  To use gcloud, you'll need to configure your indexes as a yaml file.